# Show different page for first time user

Tags: redirect, page-template, wp-redirect

As per my requirement I need to show a page say `firstpage.php` for user who visit my site for `first time` else should show home page say `homepage.php`

I created both this pages as `page-templates`

For this so far I have managed to set using cookies using below code

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) { // no cookie, so probably the first time here
        setcookie ('visited', 'yes', time() + 3600); // set visited cookie

        header("Location: index.php");
        exit(); // always use exit after redirect to prevent further loading of the page
    }
else{ 
         header("Location: index.php/first-page/");
    }
```

When I use above code it is not being redirected to required URL and resulting an error.

> The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The page is not being redirected to actual pages getting an error cannot redirect to requested URL

Comment: Where did you put above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-welcome-gate/) to get my requirement,it is managed using `cookies` we need to provide `Welcome URL` A.K.A `firstpage` in my case and them we need to select which page should be redirected for second time.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in theme functions.php:-

```
add_action('template_redirect','wdm_redirect');
function wdm_redirect(){
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$value = get_option($ip);

     if ($value == '') {                 
                update_option($ip,1);
                        wp_redirect(site_url('first-page'));
                        exit(); // always use exit after redirect to prevent further loading of the page
      } 

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't make any trick still getting the error BTW I added this code in header.php at the start of the file

Comment: and if I provide external links like google.com in header location's it is working fine.

Comment: I have modified the above code, replacing 'header' with 'wp_redirect'.

Comment: Still not solving bro :(

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: http://204.236.224.159/vt/boomerang/ open this link and you will get `The page isn't redirecting properly` error the `accept cookies` options is checked though

Comment: Try this bro....

Comment: Bro now Iam not getting any error but it is always being redirected to firstpage.php if I visit it section it should take me to homepage in real but that is not happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24950/discussion-between-wisdmlabs-and-dh47).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) with your conditional for first time visitor:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'first_time_visitor_template', 99 );

function first_time_visitor_template( $template ) {

    if ( // your conditional for first time visitor {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'first-time-template.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

[Do NOT use template_redirect](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/)

You will need to [test what solution works for a first time visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3079934/2589071).